# Generics and Spring Data JPARepository

Tags: spring, spring-data

This is a follow-up question based on Oliver Gierke's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories).

We have two tables (almost same information) but for some external reasons, cannot use a common single table. I am getting an error that the base class is not a mapped entity. Oliver Gierke has mentioned in his response that it would work only for ***Single Table***. I am assuming that is the reason. if so, could someone explain why such limitation and how can I make the following work.

Base entity:

```
   @MappedSuperclass
   public abstract class DecisionEntity {
```

Inherited classes:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="DM_INSP_TASKING_RULES_RSLT")
   public class DmInspTaskingRulesRslt extends DecisionEntity implements Serializable {

   @Entity
   @Table(name="DM_UW_REF_RULES_RSLT")
   public class DmUwRefRulesRslt extends DecisionEntity implements Serializable {
```

The Repository

```
   @Repository
   public interface DecisionManagementRepository<T extends DecisionEntity> extends    JpaRepository<DecisionEntity, Long> {
```

Have defined 'packagesToScan' and also listed all the 3 classes in persistence.xml.
I am getting the 'Non an Managed Entity' for 'DecisionEntity' class. 
I tried Inheritence Type -  'TABLE_PER_CLASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not supported by Spring Data JPA and Java Persistance API Specification.**

- Spring Data JPA Issue [DATAJPA-264](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-264)

  *Repositories: throw exception at startup if entity is a not an @Entity (e.g. for @MappedSuperclass)*

  ```
  Status: Investigating
  Resolution: Unresolved
  ```
- The [JPA specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says:

  > *A **mapped superclass**, unlike an entity, **is not queryable** and must not be passed as an argument to
  >   `EntityManager` or `Query` operations. Persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must
  >   be unidirectional.*

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using Hibernate. I was trying to implement a Factory-method kind (like in the link I shared) and ended up using JpaRepository<T>.