# How to get data from a table by entity class name using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a base entity class `BaseDictionary`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class BaseDictionary {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    protected String code;

    @Column(name = "is_enabled")
    protected Boolean enabled = true;
}
```

any child classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DB.DIC_RIGHTS_TYPE, schema = DB.SCHEMA_DIC)
public class DicRightsType extends BaseDictionary {}

@Entity
@Table(name = DB.DIC_ROLES_TYPE, schema = DB.SCHEMA_DIC)
public class DicRolesType extends BaseDictionary {}
```

There are many child classes like this.

Given an entity class name like `DicRightsType` I would like to get data from the table associated with the entity of that name. How is it possible to implement?

I wanted to use JPA repositories like this: [Using generics in Spring Data JPA repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories) but this does not suit my case because I only have the name of the entity class at runtime and do not know how to create a dynamic repository for the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own `JpaRepository` implementation to achieve this.

> **Step 1**: A repository registry

```
class RepositoryRegistrar {
  private static final Map<Class<T>, Repository<T, Serializable>> DICTIONARY = new HashMap<>();

  public static void register(Class<T> entityClass, Repository<T, Serializable> repository) {
    DICTIONARY.put(entityClass, repository);
  }

  public static Repository<T, Serializable> get(Class<T> entityClass) {
    return DICTIONARY.get(entityClass);
  }
}
```

> **Step 2**: Custom `JpaRepository` implementation to populate the registry

```
@NoRepositoryBean
class RegisteringJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {
  public RegisteringJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {{
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);

    RepositoryRegistrar.register(entityInformation.getJavaType(), this);
  }
}
```

You will have to tweak the configuration to use your custom implementation. Details for this are provided in the Spring Data JPA documentation.

> **Step 3**: Obtain repository references from the registrar

```
Repository<?, ?> getRepository(String entityClassName) {
  return RepositoryRegistrar.get(Class.forName(entityClassName));
}
```