# How do I reuse a parameter witha Spring-Data-JPA Repository?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

In looking at the [Query Creation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) for the Spring Data JPA Repositories, I'm wondering how I would reuse a parameter.  For example, how would I name the method if I wanted to do something like:

```
@Query("select c from #{#entityName} c where c.lower <= ?1 and c.upper >= ?1")
E findByConversionFor(Double amount);
```

Can that query be converted to a SpEL method name (to be used by the query builder)?

It seems like a kludge to require the same value to be passed twice:

```
E findByLowerLessThanOrEqualAndUpperGreaterThanOrEqual(Double a, Double b); // where a==b
```

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just mark your parameter with `@Param("amount")` and then will be able to use it by name:

```
@Query("select c from #{#entityName} c where c.lower <= :amount and c.upper >= :amount")
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly for the JPQL query.  Do you know how I can reuse parameters in the SpEL method?

Comment: So, there's no way to pass through "query method name creation"? (without the need of the @Query annotation)