# Spring Data JPA - Unable to reuse parameter

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm attempting to use spring-data-jpa to select an entity containing all of the provided parameter values.

My Entity looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books", schema = Constants.BENCHMARKS)
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "BookEntity.all", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("aliases"))
public class BookEntity
{
    @Id
    private String isbn = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @CollectionTable(schema = Constants.BENCHMARKS, name = "book_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_isbn"))
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<String> aliases;
}
```

My method looks as follows

```
@EntityGraph(value = "BookEntity.all", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
@Query("SELECT x FROM BookEntity x " + 
        "WHERE x IN (" + 
        "    SELECT y FROM BookEntity y" + 
        "    INNER JOIN y.aliases yt" + 
        "    WHERE yt IN (" + 
        "        :aliases" + 
        "    )" + 
        "    GROUP BY y" + 
        "    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT yt) = COUNT(" + 
        "        :aliases)" + 
        "    )")
Iterable<BookEntity> findAllByAliasesContainsAll(@Param("aliases") Collection<String> aliases);
```

When I run the method I get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 139 [select b from org.cubrc.example.hibernate.books.BookEntity b where :aliases member of b.aliases group by b.isbn having count(b) >= count( :aliases )]
```

I've already looked at [How do I reuse a parameter witha Spring-Data-JPA Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661123/how-do-i-reuse-a-parameter-witha-spring-data-jpa-repository) which is where I got my original syntax. I've also looked at a number of other posts, but none of them are actually attempting to reuse a parameter in their query. Certainly none of them are working on as basic of an example (I'm not even mixing entities here).

I guess to sum things up with an actual question, what is wrong with my query syntax that is causing it to parse in correctly?

**Response: Try including the parameter a second time**

Passing in the parameter a second time did not change the result, it still complains about the colon, leading me to believe that it's not actually a reuse issue so much as an issue with count

**Response: Try using SIZE instead of COUNT**

Changing count to SIZE resulted in a new error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unexpected expression ? found for collection function size [SELECT x FROM org.cubrc.example.hibernate.books.BookEntity x WHERE x IN (    SELECT y FROM org.cubrc.example.hibernate.books.BookEntity y    INNER JOIN y.aliases yt    WHERE yt IN (        :aliases    )    GROUP BY y    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT yt) = SIZE(        :aliases)    )]
```

**Working Workaround:**

I tried using the size manually, as in the following

```
@EntityGraph(value = "BookEntity.all", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
@Query("SELECT x FROM BookEntity x " + 
        "WHERE x IN (" + 
        "    SELECT y FROM BookEntity y" + 
        "    INNER JOIN y.aliases yt" + 
        "    WHERE yt IN (" + 
        "        :aliases" + 
        "    )" + 
        "    GROUP BY y" + 
        "    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT yt) = (" + 
        "        :aliasesSize)" + 
        "    )")
Iterable<BookEntity> findAllByAliasesContainsAll(@Param("aliases") Collection<String> aliases, @Param("aliasesSize") long aliasesSize);
```

Doing so worked, so I'll use it for now. However, it'd be nice to avoid making the user pass in two parameters when I should really only need one.

Comment: does it work if you pass List of aliases twice and use different `@Param` names?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like actual problem is you are trying to use parameter as argument for `count()` function, which is not expected. As I understand idea is to check result with size of parameter collection. For that you can try to use 'SIZE()' JPA function or pass length of aliases as another parameter.