# Spring dynamic JPA repository type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have about 30 tables that I need to fill from an XML file. And I want to use JPA for that purpose.

Now I have 30 classes annotated with `@Entity`, config that scans entities and repositories;

Also I have:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity1, Long> {
}
```

And (some controller):

```
@Autowired
public MyRepository myRepository;
...
...
MyEntity1 entity = new MyEntity(...);
myRepository.save(entity);
```

It works fine with one `@Entity` but should I define 30 repositories for that?

I thought I could do something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

and then:

```
@Autowired
public MyRepository<MyEntity1> myRepository1;
@Autowired
public MyRepository<MyEntity2> myRepository2;
```

but that gave an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach:

**Base class for all entities**:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
}
```

**Entities**:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Entity2 extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
}
```

**A common repo**:

```
public interface BaseEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<BaseEntity, Long> {
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public class BaseEntityRepoTest extends BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    private BaseEntityRepo repo;

    @Test
    public void baseEntityTest() throws Exception {

        BaseEntity entity1 = new Entity1("entity1");
        BaseEntity entity2 = new Entity2("entity2");

        repo.save(entity1);
        repo.save(entity2);

        List<BaseEntity> entities = repo.findAll();
        assertThat(entities).hasSize(2);

        entities.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: will this work for mongo db as well ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't do this and you will have to write 30 separate repositories. You can however write generic repositories when the entities share a single table inheritance. (See the answer to [Using generics in Spring Data JPA repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories))

What your code is trying to do is make a repository where the shared inheritance is on the class Object which isn't an @Entity hence the exception.

Also an additional minor note, you don't need to annotate your repositories with @Repository. Spring data automatically registers these as beans if it is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I added `@Repository` annotation when I tried to fix that I wasn't able to autowire repository, but error was that I misspelled package with repos to scan =). Anyway, you cleared my mind, thanks)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware what you are trying is not possible. Spring Data JPA needs an interface per Entity type for its repositories, Because Spring Data JPA will be creating the [query implementations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

So it is advised that you have a Repository per Entity as it will allow you to add complex `findByXXX` methods in the future also.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to get a lot copy-paste work ;)