# can spring-data dynamic create repository?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i have over 1000 repository going to create and insert data,

headerDetailLinkn00001.java

```
    @Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
    @Table(name="HDL_HEADER_DETAIL_LINK_00001")
    public class HeaderDetailLink00001{
        @Id
        @Column(name="HDL_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        @Column(name="DRI_ID")
        private Integer driId;  
        @Column(name="CSD_ID")
        private Integer csdId;

...getter and setter
}
```

HeaderDetailLink00001Repository.java

```
public interface HeaderDetailLink00001Repository extends JpaRepository<HeaderDetailLink00001,Long>{
    List<HeaderDetailLink00001> findTopByOrderByIdDesc();

}
```

controller.java

```
@GetMapping(path = "updateHeaderDetailTable")
     public @ResponseBody  int updateHeaderDetailTable(@RequestParam(value = "catNum", required = true) Integer catNum)
     {
        List<DailyHeaderResult> listBySymcatNum = DailyHeaderResultRepository.findBycatNum(catNum);
        List<HeaderDetailLink00001> chdlList = new ArrayList<HeaderDetailLink00001>();

        HeaderDetailLink00001 lastRecordOflinkTableId = HeaderDetailLink00001Repository.findTopByOrderByIdDesc().get(0);
        this.setPreviousIndex(lastRecordOflinkTableId.getCsdId());
        logger.info("sxxxxxxxxxxxxxId==="+lastRecordOflinkTableId.getCsdId()+"   "+lastRecordOflinkTableId.getDriId());

        ...
```

i am going to create HeaderDetailLink00001, HeaderDetailLink00002... HeaderDetailLink10000...etc.
is it possible make HeaderDetailLink00001 and List generate dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using generics in Spring Data JPA repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories)

Comment: following this approach i still require a lot repositories