# Is it possible to create common JpaRepository Interface?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, generics, spring-data-jpa

I have created an interface like this,

```
@Repository
public interface IJpaRepositoryCustom<T> extends JpaRepository<T,Long>{
}
```

And service class

```
@Service
public class LOVService<T>{
    @Autowired
    private IJpaRepositoryCustom<T> jpaRepositoryCustom;
}
```

But with the above code, I am getting an exception

> SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'IJpaRepositoryCustom': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)

Is there any other way to create a common JPA repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using generics in Spring Data JPA repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we want to add custom methods into all Spring Data JPA repositories, the first thing that we have to is to create a base interface which declares the custom methods.

1) **First Step:Create Base Interface**

```
    //Annotation to exclude repository interfaces from being picked up and thus in consequence getting an instance being created.
@NoRepositoryBean  
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    T findOne(ID id);

    List<T> findAll();

}
```

2) **Second Step : Implementing the Base Repository Interface**

```
public interface IUserReadOnlyRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<User,Integer> 

{
    User findById(Integer id);

    List<User> findByName(String name);

    @Query("select u from MyUser u where u.name = ?1")
    List<User> findUserByAttributeAndValueCustomQuery(String string2);   
}
```

3) **Third Step: Just Autowired into Controller/RESTController**

```
  @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @CrossOrigin
    //@EnableTransactionManagement
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        private IUserReadOnlyRepository userReadOnlyRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUserByIdReadOnlyRepository/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody User getUserById(@PathVariable Integer id)
    { 
        User user = userReadOnlyRepository.findById(id);
        return user;

    }
```

Note: It is perfectly working for me!. If any help required, ping me.

Comment: **Thanks for the reply** yes this is perfect example for add custom methods into all Spring Data JPA repositories, but my question is different. In your example you have to create multiple repository interfaces for each entity. But I want to create common repository for all the entities.

Comment: @KalanaWeerarathne Its not a good idea to have a common repo for all the entities. Pls think about SRP.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your service like this :

```
@Service
public class LOVService{

    @Autowired
    private IJpaRepositoryCustom jpaRepositoryCustom;
}
```

And your repo:

```
@Repository
public interface IJpaRepositoryCustom extends JpaRepository<YourEntityClass,Long>{
}
```

And there is no need to pass the argument to the repository if you're autowiring this.

I hope this will help.

Comment: @AngadBansode, I'm glad, I  could help. you can also upvote and accept this answer if you find this working. Thanks

Comment: **thank for the reply** I have tried this, but @Repository
public interface IJpaRepositoryCustom extends JpaRepository<T,Long>{
} has compile errors

Comment: @PawanTiwari Error:(11, 61) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class T

Comment: @KalanaWeerarathne, you just need to mention your entity class or DTO class to get the result. Or you can simply pass the Object there. I have also edited the answer.

Comment: Dear @PawanTiwari it is ok with specific entity class. I want to create common JpaRepository for all the entity classes

Comment: @Pawan Tiwari , when we add EntityClassName as Argument to jpaRepository then it is no longer common repository.