# How to create one crudrepository for multiple entity and multiple @query in single repo

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I want something just like this...i know someone will get it what i want

```
public interface PersonneRepo extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    @Query("Select p.name, p.surname, p.age, p.city, p.street from "+T+" p where p.nom = ?1 and p.prenom = ?2")
    public T customRequest(String nom, String prenom,String T);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface PersoRepo<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    @Query("Select p.name, p.surname, p.age, p.city, p.street from  #{#entityName} p where p.nom = :nom and p.prenom = :prenom")
    public T customRequest(@Param("nom") String nom, @Param("prenom") String prenom);
}
```

Comment: hello codiallo i like your solution...and i m a newbie in stackoverflow...so how do i provide value to #entityName..and thanks for this answer for my first stackoverflow question.

Comment: PROBLEM!!!! ITS THROWING "NOT A MANAGED TYPE 'T' ENTITY CANT CREATE BEAN OF PersoRepo" .what should i do now?

Comment: You does not need to set entity name. Can I see your source code where you use the repository ?

Answer (score 0):

This are three questions:

1. How to make a repository with a dynamic type parameter
2. How to make a query with dynamic from clause.
3. How to make a query method with dynamic return type.

The last you can do with [dynamic projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic) but it will only convert/wrap the result in a proxy of the desired type so that most likely won't really help you.

Number 2 you can do by writing a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) using the [Criteria API](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_criteria_api.htm).

Number 1 is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories).

Comment: hello thanks for this answer..can u please explain me whats this duplicate of  this question means i m unable to get it. and i knowsome  basics of criteria api.

Comment: It means it is basically the same question and you should read the answers to the linked question.