# JPA Repository find by param generic method

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a generic interface that extends the `JpaRepository`,
I've overridden some methods and I want to create a new generic method to find records by field name and its value.

e.g :

```
@Query("SELECT gr FROM #{#entityName}  gr WHERE gr.#{#fieldName}=(:value) AND gr.deletedAt = NULL")
List<T> findByParam();
```

`fieldName` and `value` are  `@RequestParam` objects.

```
{

    @Override
    @Query("SELECT gr FROM #{#entityName}  gr WHERE gr.deletedAt = NULL")
    List<T> findAll();

    @Override
    @Query("SELECT gr FROM #{#entityName}  gr WHERE gr.id=(:pId) AND gr.deletedAt = NULL")
    Optional<T> findById(@Param("pId") Integer pId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this has been answered in this thread :

[Using generics in Spring Data JPA repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories)

I wanted to write my own answer, but this one is already well written and should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: i don't want to write hardcode the field name like p.categories.