# How to implement Generic Repository in Java for Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I don't know how to do it. I tried this way.

```
public interface FoodRepository<E extends Object> extends JpaRepository<E, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> {
    
}


@Log4j2
@Service
public class FoodService {

    @Autowired
    private FoodRepository<FoodAudEntity> afoodRepository;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public foodService(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
 }
```

So I need a generic repository for many types of food. I got error as this:-

> Error creating bean with name 'FoodService': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'foodRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'foodRepository' defined in
> com.test.FoodRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
> is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class
> java.lang.Object

How can I implement this? is there anyway to do it?

FoodAudEntity class:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOOD_AUD_ENTITY")
public class FoodAudEntity{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

Comment: There are a lot of posts here concerning this. try to add @Repository on FoodRepository

Comment: No it doesn't help. Still, I got same error.

Comment: Ok, I have misread your error. Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417670/using-generics-in-spring-data-jpa-repositories)

Comment: What is `aFoodAudEntity`? Show its source

Comment: Pls check updated code. It was typo, it should be `FoodAudEntity`.